# Вопрос к саентистам/статистам

Tags: математика, статистика, dataset

Даны некоторые данные о сотрудниках безымянного завода. Данные описывают специфику рабочих мест [image: 30 строк данных для примера]

Доход рассчитывает на основе оклада, премии, доплат и индивидуальных надбавок. Данные о размере всех этих начислений не приводятся, так как именно их необходимо восстановить.
Подскажите в какую сторону копать, пока совсем не понимаю. Думал построить модель регрессии и по важности фичей как-то интерпретировать всё это дело, но модель получается крайне поганая, уже и бустинг пробовал, считаю по RMSE, лучший показатель 613.
В файле 2400 строк, то есть для 200 работников по каждому месяцу в году, пропусков нет.

Comment: На правила начисления з.п. могут влиять факторы, которых нет в таблице. Например: стаж, семейное положение, наличие детей, родственников на иждивении (социальные выплаты и налоговые льготы). Есть факторы которые влияют на доход отдельного месяца: отпуска, больничные, депремирование по разным причинам, командировочные выплаты. Не надейтесь на полное совпадение модели и данных. Отбрасывайте два или три хуже всего предсказанных месяца для каждого работника (отпуск и больничный), и только потом считайте среднеквадратичное отклонение.

Comment: Вы уверены, что ЗП начисляются по формуле, а не по служебной записке начальника подразделения? ))